# Can't run Docker daemon on Intel Edison

Tags: docker, intel-edison

i'm trying to install Docker on my Intel Edison that is running Ubilinux, but need some help.

i compiled the source code using this guide -> https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/project/PACKAGERS.md

... but when i try to run the daemon with "./docker daemon" i get this error:

```
xotl@ubilinux:~/docker/bundles/1.9.0-dev/binary$ sudo ./docker daemon
INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)
INFO[0000] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver "aufs"
INFO[0000] Option DefaultDriver: bridge
INFO[0000] Option DefaultNetwork: bridge
INFO[0000] Firewalld running: false
FATA[0001] Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default "bridge" network: Failed to program NAT chain: Failed to inject docker in PREROUTING chain: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
 (exit status 1)
xotl@ubilinux:~/docker/bundles/1.9.0-dev/binary$
```

Need help. =(

EDIT:

This is the output of the `sudo iptables -L -v` command:

```
xotl@ubilinux:~/docker/bundles/1.9.0-dev/binary$ sudo iptables -L -v
[sudo] password for xotl:
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  any    docker0  anywhere             anywhere                                        ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 !docker0  anywhere             anywhere                            
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  docker0 docker0  anywhere             anywhere                             

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination                            

Chain DOCKER (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

xotl@ubilinux:~/docker/bundles/1.9.0-dev/binary$
```

This is the output of the `sudo iptables -L -v -t nat`command:

```
xotl@El-Edison:~/docker/bundles/1.9.0-dev/binary$ sudo iptables -L -v -t nat
[sudo] password for xotl:
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 4 packets, 1312 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 4 packets, 1312 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 65 packets, 4940 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 65 packets, 4940 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination 
0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  any    !wlan0  10.10.0.0/21         anywhere   

Chain DOCKER (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: Add the output of: `sudo iptables -L -v` please.

Comment: Added the output of the command.

Comment: Try starting daemon with `-b` flag to and mention docker bridge.

Comment: Hi, Gursimran... i used `sudo ./docker daemon -b="wlan0"` and `sudo ./docker daemon -b="lo"`, but got the same error.

Answer (score -1):

Docker requires a 64-bit version of your Operating system (https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/ubuntulinux/).  The Intel Edison runs a 32-bit processor and will not be able to run Docker (at least, that's what I found after spending some time researching this.

Comment: There's a guy that claims he can [run Docker on a Dell PowerEdge 2550](http://mwhiteley.com/linux-containers/2013/08/31/docker-on-i386.html) with a Pentium III (a 32bit processor). Also i was able to compile it and run some docker commands.

So it should be possible to run it on a 32 bit processor.

Comment: Have you been following the Wiki https://edison.internet-share.com/wiki/Main_Page?